# How to add custom buttons in Browser Notification Web API?

Tags: javascript, browser, push-notification, service-worker

I have implemented web browser notification via

```
        var notification = new Notification(title, {
            icon: 'logoUrl',
            body: content
        });
        notification.onclick = function() {
            window.open(`https://google.com`);
        };
```

and this is working fine. I have implemented Socket.IO in backend so i am emitting notification from back-end and listening on front-end.

However i want to add a custom button in this notification, I tried googling but they all referring to ServiceWorker.

Did this not support any button related functionality ?

Comment: Did you find the solution, I also have a problem with the same issue.

Comment: No, i had to use default buttons, but if you really want some custom buttons, you should go with ServiceWorker notification implementation.